# Select row in which one element related with an id appears in other table where the id is the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

Table 1:

| Number PK | Word PK |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | J |
| 3 | K |
| 3 | B |

Table 2:

| Number2 | Word2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | X |
| 3 | B |

I want to select the rows of the second table in which the word (Word2) is related with the rows of table 1 in which (Number Pk) is the same as (Number 2). For example, in the first row of the second table we can see Number2=1 and Word2=A, so I would want the program to search in the first table where Number Pk=1 and see if it is related with A, so it is related with A, B and C. So it meets the condition that it is related with A, so that row of the second column would be a solution.

Output:

| Number | Word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 3 | B |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT T1.NumberPK, T1.WorkPK
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.NumberPK = T2.NumberPK
WHERE T1.WordPK = T2.WordPK
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Microsoft SQL Server delimiters `[ ]`. MySQL does not support that type of delimiter. (I did not downvote.)

Comment: I modified the query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT `Table 1`.`Number PK`, MIN(`Table 2`.`Word PK`) AS Word
FROM `Table 1` JOIN `Table 2` ON `Table 1`.`Number PK` = `Table 2`.`Number2`
GROUP BY `Number PK`;
```

If you have other columns in `Table 2` you wish to include:

```
SELECT t.`Number PK`, t.`Word`, ...others...
FROM (
  SELECT `Table 1`.`Number PK`, `Table 1`.`Word PK` AS Word, ...others...
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `Table 1`.`Number PK` ORDER BY `Table ``.`Word PK`) AS rownum
  FROM `Table 1` JOIN `Table 2` ON `Table 1`.`Number PK` = `Table 2`.`Number2`
) AS t
WHERE t.rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but this logically or similar should work.

```
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE table2.word2 IN (SELECT WordPK FROM table1 WHERE table1.numberPK=table2.Number2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact field and table names but presumably something along the lines of this would do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT number, word FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT number, word FROM table2
```

Comment: MySQL does not support INTERSECT. This has been a feature request for a long time: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31336

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice the mysql tag. An inner join or an exists query it'll be then I suppose.